# Speeding up NDSolve for system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I am wondering if there is a way to speed up this function that solves a system of ordinary differential equations with NDSolve? Thus far I've tried specifying a few different methods such as LSODA, BDF, StiffnessSwitching; however, none of these has significantly affected the execution time. Is it possible to use Compile here?

```
Atotal = 100.; 
Btotal = 100.; 
Ctotal = 100.; 
Rtotal = 100.; 
input = Table[i, {i, 0.5, 6.5, 1.0}];
runs = Table[i, {i, 1, 6}];
simtime = 60*{15., 30.};

 chiscore[input_Real, runs_Integer, simtime_Real, k1_Real,
  k1m_Real, k2_Real, k2m_Real, a_Real, k3_Real, k3m_Real, 
  k4_Real, k4m_Real, k5_Real, k5m_Real, k6_Real, k6m_Real,
  kn_Real, kc_Real, k8_Real, k8m_Real, k9_Real, k9m_Real,
  k10_Real, k11_Real, negoff_, Atotal_Real, Btotal_Real,
  Ctotal_, Rtotal_Real] := 
 Block[{soln, t, A, B, Cin, Cout, R},
     soln = NDSolve[
        {
          Derivative[1][A][t] == (((k1*input)/(1 + negoff*(R[t]/k10)))*
          (Atotal - A[t]))/(k1m + (Atotal - A[t])) - (k2*A[t])/(k2m + A[t]),
          Derivative[1][B][t] == (k3*A[t]*(Btotal - B[t]))/
          (k3m + (Btotal - B[t])) - ((k4 + k11*R[t])*B[t])/(k4m + B[t]),
          Derivative[1][Cin][t] == ((k5*B[t] + a*Cin[t])*(Ctotal - Cin[t] - Cout[t]))/
          (k5m + (Ctotal - Cin[t] - Cout[t])) - (k6*Cin[t])/(k6m + Cin[t])
          - kn*Cin[t] + kc*Cout[t], 
          Derivative[1][Cout][t] == kn*Cin[t] - kc*Cout[t],
          Derivative[1][R][t] == (k8*Cout[t]*(Rtotal - R[t]))/
          (k8m + (Rtotal - R[t])) - (k9*R[t])/(k9m + R[t]),
        A[0] == 0.,
        B[0] == 0., 
        Cin[0] == 0.,
        Cout[0] == 0.,
        R[0] == 0.
       },
      {A, B, Cin, Cout, R},
      {t, 0., simtime}][[1]] 
  ]

Table[chiscore[input[[i]], runs[[i]], simtime[[2]], 4.0, 0.0043, 
 0.0713, 0.039, .02, 1.561, 0.502, 0.0752, 0.000284, 1.48658, 
 0.0575, 0.746837, 0.442668, 0.182, 0.00176, 0.0375, 2.73359, 
 0.000685, 0.0567, 0.1735, 0.0367, 1.0, Atotal, Btotal, Ctotal,
 Rtotal][[1]],
{i, 1, 5}]; // Timing
```

Comment: Well one problem is that I've used D as a variable... Need to update with a better name

Comment: You can reduce the `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`.  I don't see how to use `Compile`.  How much faster do you want it to be?

Comment: Perhaps the use of `ParallelTable` is an option. As for `Compile`, `NDSolve` auto compiles what it can.

Comment: An order of magnitude would be great because I solve this system for many different parameter sets. I'll try changing these two goals.

Comment: @user21 ParallelTable does speed up the function. That's good to know about Compile.

Comment: @user21 Interestingly, NDSolve appears to automatically select LSODA which runs in about .05 seconds, however BDF runs at .03 seconds, and of course StiffnessSwitching is the slowest at .08 seconds. I've verified that all of these methods give the correct result for the system.

Comment: Since you are interested in different parameter sets try to use `ParametricNDSolve` and find the sensitivity of those parameters. There is a section on sensitivity computation in the [ParametricNDSolve ref.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html?q=ParametricNDSolve)

Comment: @user21 So I've used parallel ndsolve to study the sensitivity of the system for each parameter and have used that to constrain certain parameters. Interestingly, although ParallelTable appears faster than the serial call to each the function. The overall runtime for the code is much slower than the serial evaluation. I'm a bit miffed as too what is going on. Any thoughts as too why this happens?

Comment: @tarhawk, no, unfortunately not, it might be related to communication overhead, but that is a pure guess.